# Android - Background service stops when its invoker activity is destroyed

Tags: android, android-service

I have an always-running background service, started on my MainActivity. The problem is, **when MainActivity is destroyed, my service gets restarted**. This scenario is the only one in which the service stops, so the "always-running" thing is working well.

**I would like to know why this is happening, and what I could do to prevent it.**

My service is not bound to my activity, because I don't need it.

**The service:**

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    ...
    public LocationService() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // Some initialization logic here
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    ...
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Start location service in background
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: what's wrong with service restart?

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar Your comment isn't correct and makes no sense. Services don't run on "a thread". Some calls to the `Service` run on the main thread (and you can't change that), and a `Service` can start as many other threads as it wants. A `Service` is an object. Objects occupy space, not time. You are confusing space and time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing because I don't have enough data. When your `MainActivity` is destroyed, the OS process hosting your application has no active activities in it, just your `Service`. Android recognizes that the process isn't hosting any live activities, so it kills the process to free resources. Since your `Service` returned `START_STICKY`, Android then schedules your `Service` for a restart. The `Service` gets reinstantiated in a new OS process.

You could run your `Service` in a separate OS process to test this theory. Just add

```
android:process=":remote"
```

to the manifest entry for the `<service>`. This may have other implications on your application, so be sure you understand that.

In any case, Android will randomly kill OS processes that host only services, even if they returned `START_STICKY`. There isn't any way to prevent that, especially on low-end devices with limited resources. It is Android's way of cleaning house ;-)

Comment: Tnx for the good explanation. I have a query about service. I managed to run service in background forever but onStartCommand() is not called whenever the app is removed on click of button "Remove all application from background". I've seen that button on Samsung and LG devices. It works fine when user remove app with swipe.

Comment: It is possible that "remove all application from background" is doing a "force stop" on the application. In that case, Android won't automatically restart the `Service` because the application is in the "stopped state". In this case, the user must start the application manually himself. You'll need to search some more or experiment a bit to see if this is what is happening.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look in it.